# How to temporary redirect when doing maintanace on Glassfish 3

Tags: ubuntu, glassfish, webserver, java-ee-6

I Want to redirect users to a temporary URL when I do maintenance on the application runing om my Glassfish server. I dont't want to change my server providers DNS config just for this, it must be something more easy. Something that I can control from inside Glassfish 3.1, when I do redeployment or mucking about.

What can I do to redirect when the Glassfish instance is still running and what can I do when I Glassfish instance is stopped, but the Ubuntu server is still running.

What is the best practice for redirect users when doing maintenance when working with Glassfish and web-servers in general ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution if you got a classic setup with an Apache web server with mod_jk / mod_proxy talking to your Glassfish server could be redirecting on 503 HTTP error code to a static HTML file served by your Apache web server.

Comment: Yes, that is maybe an option. Although I need to bring an extra process, gateway = more config and memory footprint.

Comment: @Chris your application server is not backed by a http frontend server ?

Comment: that is correct. Glassfish is well equipt for fronting work, at least 3.1 and later. The http-server part of Glassfish is a tomcat, plus more security.

Comment: I'm afraid your setup will require an extra frontend server when your glassfish is turned down. One could imagine spawning a apache when taking down your glassfish and stopping it as glassfish starts.

Comment: Hi, you are maybe correct. There are not many other options I guess.

Comment: Additionnally, setting up a frontend server could allow you to easily load balance between two Glassfish instances for example, I highly recommend you doing so.